# What is the effect of buffer(0) in the collectLatest implementation in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The explanation of the implementation of `collectLatest` in the Kotlin source code is as follows:

````kotlin
public suspend fun <T> Flow<T>.collectLatest(action: suspend (value: T) -> Unit) {
    /*
     * Implementation note:
     * buffer(0) is inserted here to fulfil user's expectations in sequential usages, e.g.:
     * ```
     * flowOf(1, 2, 3).collectLatest {
     *     delay(1)
     *     println(it) // Expect only 3 to be printed
     * }
     * ```
     *
     * It's not the case for intermediate operators which users mostly use for interactive UI,
     * where performance of dispatch is more important.
     */
    mapLatest(action).buffer(0).collect()
}
````

It says "buffer(0) is inserted here to fulfil user's expectations in sequential usages", but the results I get when I don't use buffer(0) are the same as when I use buffer(0):

```kotlin
    flowOf(1, 2, 3).mapLatest {
        delay(1)
        println(it)
    }.buffer(0).collect() // print 3

    flowOf(1, 2, 3).mapLatest {
        delay(1)
        println(it)
    }.collect() // print 3 too
```

So I guess buffer(0) doesn't work here. Can someone help explain it.

When I looked at the source code of mapLatest, there was a comment saying "This operator is buffered by default and size of its output buffer can be changed by applying subsequent buffer operator".

````kotlin
/**
 * Returns a flow that emits elements from the original flow transformed by [transform] function.
 * When the original flow emits a new value, computation of the [transform] block for previous value is cancelled.
 *
 * For example, the following flow:
 * ```
 * flow {
 *     emit("a")
 *     delay(100)
 *     emit("b")
 * }.mapLatest { value ->
 *     println("Started computing $value")
 *     delay(200)
 *     "Computed $value"
 * }
 * ```
 * will print "Started computing a" and "Started computing b", but the resulting flow will contain only "Computed b" value.
 *
 * This operator is [buffered][buffer] by default and size of its output buffer can be changed by applying subsequent [buffer] operator.
 */
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
public fun <T, R> Flow<T>.mapLatest(@BuilderInference transform: suspend (value: T) -> R): Flow<R> =
    transformLatest { emit(transform(it)) }
````

I don't quite understand why it says `mapLatest`'s buffer can be changed by applying subsequent buffer operator, because when a new flow arrives, the previous flow will be canceled. What is the meaning of changing the buffer?

Maybe this question should be "what is the effect of the buffer in `mapLatest`/`transformLatest`?".

Answer (score 1):

A potential hint is that `buffer` somehow creates another coroutine.

```
fun main(): Unit = runBlocking { // this: CoroutineScope
    val flow1 = flowOf(1, 2, 3)

    // not cancelled (cancelling this: CoroutineScope would cancel the children as well)
    launch {
        while (true){
            println("still running")
            delay(1000)
        }
    }

    flow1.collectLatest {// it: Int
        delay(10) // delays the collector coroutine
        println(it)
    }
}
```

```
still running
3
still running
still running
...
```

The same thing happens with `mapLatest`.

```
flow1.mapLatest {// it: Int
        delay(10) // delays the collector coroutine
        println(it)
    }.collect()
```

I think that the normal `collect` delays the current coroutine.

```
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    flow1.collect{
        delay(1000)
        println("$it: ${System.currentTimeMillis() - start}")
    }
    println("${System.currentTimeMillis() - start}")
```

```
1: 1018
2: 2023
3: 3034
3034
```

However, I am not able to print a different thread to confirm it.

```
val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    println("${Thread.currentThread()} $coroutineContext")
    flow1.collectLatest {
        delay(1000)
        println("$it: ${System.currentTimeMillis() - start} ${Thread.currentThread()} $coroutineContext")
    }
    println("${System.currentTimeMillis() - start}")
```

```
Thread[main,5,main] [BlockingCoroutine{Active}@532760d8, BlockingEventLoop@57fa26b7]
3: 1095 Thread[main,5,main] [BlockingCoroutine{Active}@532760d8, BlockingEventLoop@57fa26b7]
1107
```

---

I tried having delays inside the flow. The emission is affected by the time it takes to collect.

```
val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    fun elapsedTime() = System.currentTimeMillis() - start

    val flow1 = flow{
        for(i in 1..5){
            emit(i)
            println("EMIT $i: ${Thread.currentThread()} ${elapsedTime()}")
            delay(1000)
        }
    }

    flow1.collect{
        println("COLLECT $it: ${Thread.currentThread()} ${elapsedTime()}")
        delay(2000)
    }
```

```
COLLECT 1: Thread[main,5,main] 24
EMIT 1: Thread[main,5,main] 2053
COLLECT 2: Thread[main,5,main] 3064
EMIT 2: Thread[main,5,main] 5067
```

With `collectLatest`, the flow doesn't wait for the collector.

```
COLLECT 1: Thread[main,5,main] 247
EMIT 1: Thread[main,5,main] 258
COLLECT 2: Thread[main,5,main] 1270
EMIT 2: Thread[main,5,main] 1270
```

---

I came up with an example to understand what buffer capacity does.

```
flow1.onEach {
        println("ON_EACH $it: ${elapsedTime()}")
    }.mapLatest {
        println("MAP $it: ${elapsedTime()}")
        it
    }.buffer(0).collect{
        println("COLLECT $it: ${elapsedTime()} ")
        delay(2000)
    }
```

```
ON_EACH 1: 116
MAP 1: 120
ON_EACH 2: 123
MAP 2: 124
ON_EACH 3: 124
COLLECT 1: 130 
MAP 3: 141
COLLECT 3: 2147
```

With a capacity of 3, everything gets collected.

```
ON_EACH 1: 131
MAP 1: 134
ON_EACH 2: 138
MAP 2: 140
ON_EACH 3: 140
MAP 3: 140
COLLECT 1: 147 
COLLECT 2: 2158 
COLLECT 3: 4172
```

Without specifying a capacity of 0, it seems that mapLatest uses an infinite capacity.

```
flow1.onEach {
        println("ON_EACH $it: ${elapsedTime()}")
    }.mapLatest {
        println("MAP $it: ${elapsedTime()}")
        it
    }.collect{
        println("COLLECT $it: ${elapsedTime()} ")
        delay(2000)
    }
```

```
ON_EACH 10: 247
MAP 10: 247
COLLECT 1: 257 
COLLECT 2: 2270 
COLLECT 3: 4274 
COLLECT 4: 6284 
COLLECT 5: 8298 
COLLECT 6: 10311 
COLLECT 7: 12316 
COLLECT 8: 14323 
COLLECT 9: 16329 
COLLECT 10: 18341
```

What's confusing is that the buffer affects the collector, but in the code of `collectLatest`, the action is part of the flow `mapLatest(action).buffer(0).collect()`.

Comment: But I still don't understand the difference between `mapLatest(action).collect()` and `mapLatest(action).buffer(0).collect()`, I think they have the same power because there is no implementation or delay in `collect()` which will not cause a flow rate mismatch between producers and consumers. All the processing work is done in the action of `mapLatest(action)`, and the buffer of `buffer(0)` seems unnecessary for `collect()`.

Comment: @sulv I am confused as well, I can't find an example to contradict "user's expectations in sequential usages". `collect()` uses `collect(NopCollector)`, so `mapLatest(action).buffer(0).collect()` avoids calling `NopCollector`, which does nothing. Maybe it's just about performance, but I can't think of a scenario where an UI element would overwhelm the channel of a buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit I am not familiar with this code, but the buffer(0) part is likely preventing any data from being buffered before getting processed.

For example, I was working on a bash script yesterday that was redirecting output from a program into a file.  Instead of the lines being redirected from the running program being live, as they would be if I was watching it in the console, it would appear a few lines at a time after the output from the program filled the buffer.

Since I was also reading this file in another program, this would lead to a delay in the input being picked up in the second program and was causing issues.

I suspect, like it was in my case, that this may not even show up all of the time but may only appear in certain cases.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I didn't quite understand the example of redirecting output you mentioned. In fact, when the `mapLatest` function is processing event A, if event B arrives before A is processed to completion, it will cancel the processing of A and start processing B. Then what effect does the buffer of `mapLatest` have in this situation?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).